# Copying latex equations from Word doc to PowerPoint with python

Tags: python-docx, python-pptx

I've been trying to get a formula from Word and display it on PowerPoint.

However I have encountered a problem the formula that is being shown on the presentation slide, has nothing to do with the original formula in the Word file.

The original formula:
[image]

The output in the Presentation slide:
[image]

I tried to trace back the cause with no result, I am guessing the problem is caused by the way the formulas are being read, is there any other way to go about it? If not, is any other library or language that can do this? I want to add animation to each text box that contains a formula as well, is that possible with python-pptx? Maybe something that can do that as well.

Here is my code:

```py
import re

import latex2mathml.converter
from pptx import Presentation
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import docxlatex as latex
from lxml import etree


def latex_to_word(latex_input):
    mathml = latex2mathml.converter.convert(latex_input, display="block")

    tree = etree.fromstring(mathml)
    xslt = etree.parse(
        'MML2OMML.XSL'
    )
    transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)
    new_dom = transform(tree)

    wrapper = etree.fromstring(
        '''<a14:m xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main">
            <m:oMath xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math">
            </m:oMath>
        </a14:m>''')
    wrapper.getchildren()[0].append(new_dom.getroot())
    return wrapper


def getLatexEquations(text):
    return re.findall(r'\$([^$].*?)\$', text)

latexDoc = latex.Document('demo.docx')
prs = Presentation()

title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6] # blank slide
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
left = width = height = Inches(1)

equations = getLatexEquations(latexDoc.get_text())

for equation in equations:
    txBoxNum = equations.index(equation) + 1.5
    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, Inches(1 * txBoxNum), width, height)
    tf = txBox.text_frame
    txBoxP = tf.add_paragraph()
    txBoxP._element.append(latex_to_word(equation, for_ppt=True))
    tf

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

I tried outputting the same formula to another word document this time but the result is the same:

```py
import latex2mathml.converter
from docx import Document
import docxlatex as latex
from lxml import etree

def latex_to_word(latex_input):
    mathml = latex2mathml.converter.convert(latex_input)

    tree = etree.fromstring(mathml)
    xslt = etree.parse(
        'MML2OMML.XSL'
    )
    transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)
    new_dom = transform(tree)

    return new_dom.getroot()

document = Document()
latexDoc = latex.Document('demo.docx').get_text()


p = document.add_paragraph()
p._element.append(latex_to_word(latexDoc))

document.save('test2.docx')
```